# Add a page to nodes with comment form

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using Drupal 7.

I would want to add a page to my nodes, with the comment form (only), and a link in the tab menu to reach it :

[image]

I tried with views but I did not arrive there.

Do you know the simplest way to reach there?

Answer (score -1):

I believe [Display Suite module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) will do the trick.